# iPad iOS 6 crash

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, crash-log

My game is crashing at launch on iPads for some users with some mystical reason.
But it works fine on iPhone (iPad and iPhone versions are different apps, but technically is the same builds, just different targets)
It happens after updating the app to version 1.1.1

The game had previous updates which works correctly. (updating few months ago 1.0 -> 1.1 was perfect)

Version 1.1.1 was created for iOS 6 compatibility- Landscape GameCenter bug + added few SDKs (Urban Airship, Flurry, TapJoy etc) + app name was changed

As far I know - crash happens for users who updated their iPads to iOS 6.0 and updated the game after that.

App update process working fine for me and few other test devices, but a lot of users experienced the crash and wrote 1* comments in App Store. 
Bug was unable to reproduce.

One more weird thing:

Only thing I have is single crash report.
Please help me to read it, I will be really appreciated!

**[Download crash report here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j3g9kek2pobye43/ttf2HD_2012-10-12-003303_iPad.crash)**

Comment: Unfortunately, your crash report contains no stack trace and limited information in general, so it will be extremely difficult to ascertain the nature of the crash.

Comment: I had similiar problem just few weeks ago with two of my apps after adding flurry. I removed it and users are happy again. I'm not saying it's flurry's fault, but in my case this was the case.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems with flurry and only figured it out after adding a crash reporting SDK to my app.  I've tried a few.  Here's a decent free one:

www.crittercism.com